# Is it safe to use IEnumerable ForEach extension in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ienumerable

If one take a look into `EnumerableExtensions.cs` file, one can see

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms.Internals
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     For internal use by the Xamarin.Forms platform.
    //
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     For internal use by the Xamarin.Forms platform.
        //
        public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action);
    }
}
```

So my question is regarding these comments *For internal use*. Does they mean any kind of warnings and this code should not be used by developers? Can I use this method in my code?

Really, I'm using it now and it works, but I'm bothering about some pitfalls on this way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This means that you, the developer, are not supposed to use it. This means that Xamarin can remove it at any point if they want to, they could change how it works, or break its signature, etc, etc.

Comment: As canton7 said, it isnt designed for you to use, what you can do is create your own extension method that does the same that they do with the foreach and be on the safe side

Comment: @nalnpir, it's good idea :-)

Comment: Or just use a normal `foreach` loop, which has exactly the same restrictions where it can be written and is just the usual language feature.

Comment: Also see https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/: there's a good reason why `IEnumerable<T>.ForEach` doesn't exist, and `List<T>.ForEach` is regarded as a mistake. Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @canton7, thank you, that's interesting

Comment: Funny though, even though this method is evil (and it is), Xamarin uses it, but demands its for internal use.. \*scratches head\*.

Comment: Someone decided that the convenience was worth the evilness in a small number of cases (it's only used a handful of times), and it falls into the category of "internal helpers" not "public API", because there's no need to expose it as an public API: it's nothing to do with Xamarin.Forms itself, and there's no need to spend time documenting it or promise that it will never change or be removed. Xamarin.Forms isn't a general toolkit of helpers: it has a very specific purpose, and internal utilities which are nothing to do with that purpose are kept internal. You'd do the same with your libraries